# Send mails using EXCHANGE SERVER (Microsoft Outlook web access)in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I know how to send mails using outlook installed in same machine, where I'm running my code. 
Now, the requirement here is to access exchange server (Microsoft OWA) of my organization for sending mails in asp.net code.

Is it possible? If yes, then plz throw some light.

Thnx

***UPDATE***

**Got the Solution. Posting my working code here for any one who wants help. happy coding !**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
    //service.AutodiscoverUrl("youremailaddress@yourdomain.com");

    service.Url = new Uri("https://yourwebmailaddress.com/ews/Exchange.asmx");

    service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    //service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password");


    EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
    message.Subject = "My auto mail from exchange server";
    message.Body = "hi everyone !";
    message.ToRecipients.Add("brad.pitt@hollywood.com");
    message.Save();

    message.SendAndSaveCopy();

    Label1.Text = "Success !";    
}
```

**Another Question:** How to use microsoft exchange 2003 ?? 'coz EWS is not supported in there. Please update any idea...?

Comment: what do you mean? OWA is merely a website to access your exchange server. Perhaps your question is how to send emails using exchange?

Comment: @ oskar - Question edited. thnx for notifying. Yes I want access to exchange server through my code. How to determine the exchange server's address?

Comment: SMTP is what is used to send emails. MS Exchange does support SMTP. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Please post the solution as a new answer, don't make it part of the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send emails using the Exchange Web Services API (EWS).  EWS is a set of old fashioned ASMX web services hosted on the same server as OWA. Microsoft has even published an open source managed API wrapper [on GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api) for EWS.

Here is an example on how to send emails using EWS:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Send-Email-with-Exchange-50189e57

The GitHub readme also includes links to samples.

Usually EWS can be found at `http://yourexchangeserver/ews/exchange.asmx` but with the managed API you can use autodiscovery to automatically find the address of EWS on your Exchange server.

**Update regarding Exchange 2003:**

You can access the Exchange 2003 mail store via HTTP using WebDAV.  WebDAV is a bit of a pain to use because you may have to use Forms Based Authentication (FBA) if that is what your OWA installation requires (in comparison EWS can use Windows Authentication even if OWA on Exchange 2007/2010 is using FBA).

I have never tried sending mails using WebDAV for Exchange (although I have used WebDAV for a number of other things) but I found an [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms878112) that you may want to try.  It uses Windows Authentication so it will not work if your Exchange 2003 OWA is set up to use FBA.  If you need to use FBA let me know - I may have some sample code somewhere that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to send email through your organizations exchange server from asp.net, but you wouldn't want to use OWA.

There is a web site dedicated to .Net email that should give you some sample code.  See:
http://www.systemnetmail.com/

Understand that you will need to get the exchange administrator to give your asp.net machine access to the SMTP port (this usually Port 25) on the exchange server and set up permissions to allow you to relay messages thru the server.

Comment: thnx mark. I understand the point that why I should not go for using OWA. But in my current scenario, I want to give it a try first. Later I may go for other options. System.Net.Mail <-- this I know, as I used it to sent mails in asp.net using outlook(pre configured with user) installed in same machine where my code executes.

Comment: System.Net.Mail does not require outlook to be installed on the Asp.net machine.  
@Jakob  I had never heard of EWS.  That's pretty slick